# Do I lose my account if I sign into game center

Tags: clash-of-clans, game-center

I started playing clash of clans on my iPod without signing into Game Center. I'm worried that if I sign in into GC, might lose it.

Can I lose my account if I sign in?

Answer (score 4):

## Yes, and no.

*It's really up to what you chose when prompted to do so...*

When you sign into Game Center (or Google Play), you're essentially linking your village with a viable account; an identifiable account with a password and username.
If your Game Center account does not have a village linked to it, your village will link to your Game Center account, and nothing else happens thus allowing you to access the same village on any device with the same Game Center account.

However, if you already have a village linked with that Game Center account, you'll be given the option to destroy your current village and replace it with the village stored on your Game Center account, *or* destroy your linked village on your Game Center account and keep the current one instead.

There should be a dialog that looks something like this:
[image]

---

As for achievements, any unearned achievements on your Game Center account that your village has will automatically be added. As for the other way around (having an achievement on Game Center that the village does not have), nobody's really experimented with that *yet*.

Answer (score -1):

No, it will not remove your account instead the Game Center will be your saving and achievement storage :)